# Auto-Download Using iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am making available a file for users to download on my site. What I want to achieve is auto-download functionality, so that whenever a user visits a download page, download dialog should automatically appear and if they click ***Run*** file should get executed. The logic I am using is this -

```
<iframe src='download_link' height='1' width='1' style='display:none;'>
```

I am placing this line at the end of the *html* code, and works fine, except when some system has Anti-Virus like for example **Norton Internet Security**.

I want to know whether its even possible to overcome this problem, or is there any other secured way to provide the same functionality to users ?

Comment: what if you remove the `style="display:none;"` ? That might trigger the virusscanner (and possibly trigger e.g. google to mark your site as infected)

Answer (score 0):

To make such a download possible, you could use the following:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='download_link'">
```

As a meta-tag, this should be placed in the  of your file. However, you could make a js-function to edit the location after loading.

```
location.href = 'download_link';
```

With this, the browser will load the file and download it, but will preserve the old document. If the file will be something that can be opened in the browser (e.g. a pdf-document), you'll need to open it in an other tab via Javascript.